# Why are some questions blue on the front page

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Why are some questions showing up with a blue background on the front page? It looks like this is just the "guitars" tag. Is this a SE feature based on my usage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is indeed.  You should see [guitar](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guitar) under the Frequented Tags section on the right side of the questions list.